# Microsoft Access 2010 interdependencies in Forms (fill out one cell, automatically fill another)

Tags: ms-access, vba

In excel, I know this is the VLOOKUP function, however, being a beginner at Access, I have no clue how to do this.

I have halls (from A to H), who all have their own teamleader (eg A-->Ben, B-->Michael, C-->Dave, etc). I would like to select just the hall, and the teamleader will automatically show up in the next field on the form. At the end, all will be registered in a table.

I have currently build this equation to fill out a specific value in a cell (dependent on the value of another cell), but it is giving an error message. What am I doing wrong?

```
Option Compare Database 

Dim db As DAO.Database 
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Private Sub Hal_AfterUpdate() 
    Set db = CurrentDb    
    'SELECT Voormannen.Voorman, Voormannen.Hal 
    'FROM Voormannen 
    'WHERE (((Voormannen.Hal)=[Formulieren]![DSM formulier]![Hal]));

    strSQL = "SELECT Voormannen.Voorman, Voormannen.Hal FROM Voormannen WHERE [Voormannen]![Hal]=[Forms]![DSM formulier]![Hal]" 
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    rst.MoveFirst
    Me.Tekst304 = rst![Voorman]
    rst.Close 

    Set rst = Nothing 
    Me.Refresh 
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use _DLookup_ for this. Look up the on-line help.

Comment: It really is important to indicate the line of code where the error message is generated. I'll bet the error is due to >WHERE [Voormannen]![Hal]=[Forms]![DSM formulier]![Hal]"< I think you need: >WHERE [Voormannen]![Hal] = '" &  [Forms]![DSM formulier]![Hal] & "'" <  If the field is alphanumeric, then you need quotes (or single-quotes) around the value.

Comment: Thanks Gustav and Wayne!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your SQL string returns a correct dataset, try replacing this:

Me.Tekst304 = rst![Voorman]

with this:

Me.Tekst304.Text = rst("Voorman")

If your SQL string does not return a correct dataset, try changing it to this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Voorman, Hal FROM Voormannen " & _
"WHERE Hal = '" & Forms![DSM formulier]!Hal.Text & "'"
```

You need to surround your control reference with ampersands (&) otherwise VBA doesn't know you're referencing a control.